# How to make bot commands SPACE Insensitive

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to make my bot command space insensitive. Everytime I do something like "go rps" the unknown command thing still outputs even though go rps is a command. For command like "view" the unknown command thing works. I have my code linked below! I figured out how to make it case insensitive but not space insensitive.

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    let validCommands = ["go rps", "go mountains", "go hills", "go cannons", "go left", "go east", "go west", "view", "holler"];
    // Added the .toLowerCase() function vvv to make everything work both ways 
    const args = message.content.toLowerCase().substring(PREFIX.length).slice().split(/ /);;
    const command = args.shift();
    const isValid = validCommands.includes(command); 
    const unknowncommand = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle('SCOTT')
    .setDescription('You\'ve entered an unknown command. \nUse **!help** to see all available commands.')   
    if(!isValid){
        if(message.author.bot) return;
        return message.channel.send(unknowncommand), console.log(`[SCOTT] ${message.author.username} entered an unknown command in "${message.guild.name}".`);
    }
});
```

This code I found online a few hours ago. The only thing that worked. Can someone please help me get the spacing ones, like "go rps" should be working. Anyways, please help. Thanks.

Comment: You need spit commands into files and use regex fo find command or command aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    let validCommands = ["go rps", "go mountains", "go hills", "go cannons", "go left", "go east", "go west", "view", "holler"];
    const command = message.content.toLowerCase().substring(PREFIX.length)
    console.log(command)
    const isValid = validCommands.includes(command); 
    const unknowncommand = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle('SCOTT')
    .setDescription('You\'ve entered an unknown command. \nUse **!help** to see all available commands.')   
    if(!isValid){
        if(message.author.bot) return;
        return message.channel.send(unknowncommand), console.log(`[SCOTT] ${message.author.username} entered an unknown command in "${message.guild.name}".`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218785/discussion-on-answer-by-levi-op-how-to-make-bot-commands-space-insensitive).

Answer (score 0):

to make the text space insensitive you might want yo just remove all the space characters.

also don't forget to change your whitelist to have space insensitive strings

```js
const text = 'some text with spaces and    tabs';
console.log(text.replace(/\s/gm, ''));
```